# IDisposable disposed before exception filter only in async methods

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, exception, idisposable

I would like to understand in more detail how .Net Exception Filters work, specifically with regards to `async` methods and `IDisposable` objects in `using` blocks.

There is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/677) regarding logging scope being lost in exception filters for `async` ASP.Net Core request delegates. The scope is stored in [`ConsoleLogScope`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/ConsoleLogScope.cs#L54) and is lost when the disposable is disposed.

In the following code, there are two scenarios demonstrated:

First:

- Synchronous RequestDelegate throws an exception
- Exception filter is executed and returns
- `ConsoleLogScope.DisposableScope` is disposed

Second:

- Asynchronous RequestDelegate throws an exception
- `ConsoleLogScope.DisposableScope` is disposed
- Exception filter is executed and returns

**Note that merely marking the lambda as `async` is sufficient to introduce the second behaviour.** The GitHub issue says it's due to the `await Task.Delay(100)`, but I've found it happens without that line.

Why is this? Is it `AsyncTaskMethodBuilder` catching exceptions, so the filters never get executed?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.AddConsole(options => options.IncludeScopes = true);
                logging.AddFilter("Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning);
            })
            .Configure(app =>
            {
                var logger = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

                app.Map("/sync", subApp =>
                {
                    // Exception handler
                    subApp.Use(async (context, next) =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await next();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) when (LogError(logger, ex))
                        {
                        }
                    });
                    // Logic
                    subApp.Run((context) =>
                    {
                        using (logger.BeginScope("UserId:100"))
                        {
                            throw new InvalidOperationException("Something went wrong");
                        }
                    });
                });

                app.Map("/async", subApp =>
                {
                    // Exception handler
                    subApp.Use(async (context, next) =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await next();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) when (LogError(logger, ex))
                        {
                        }
                    });
                    // Logic
                    subApp.Run(async (context) =>
                    {
                        using (logger.BeginScope("UserId:100"))
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(100); // Force TaskAwaiter
                            throw new InvalidOperationException("Something went wrong");
                        }
                    });
                });
            })
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }

    public static bool LogError(ILogger logger, Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception");
        return true;
    }
}
```